# Two types of orders ERD

Tags: database, database-design, erd

im new to database design and im trying to create an ERD for a pharmacy that sells products online and also accepts repeat prescriptions orders to customers.

Here is the link to my ERD:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmeOD.png

I'm wondering how i could only make use of only one 'payment' and 'card details' entity for both orders, so have i have 2 entities for each order. Would i be able to make a relationship between the ORDER TYPE entity and payment/card details entity.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is not really clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to find a good reason forh aving both `Prescription_Order` and `Product_Order`.  There should just be an `Orders` (pluralized because ORDER is a reserved word everywhere) table, where the `Customer_Recurring_Order` table (with a natural key of references to `Customer` and `Product`) breaks out the rules for a customer's recurring orders, regardless of whether they are prescription in nature or not.  Your medicine attribute properly belongs as a record in the product table.

Also, the `Card Details` table should properly be linked to one or more `Customer`, as I'm pretty sure that card details are functionally dependent on the existence of a customer.

Once you've cleaned those up, you only need one `Payment` or `Card Details` entity.  A good design principle to remember is that if two entities have all the same attributes, they probably aren't two different entities.

Why didn't you break out shipping information into a separate entity, `Order_Shipment`.  Will all shipments always contain all portions of a customer's order?

Answer (score 1):

You have some flaws in your design though:

1. `Product Order` and `Order Product`. Developers and admins will go crazy remembering which table is used for what.
2. It is unclear why you have 2 `Card Details`? Instead of adding `Perscription_PaymentID` and `Product_PaymentID` columns to the `Card Details` do it the other way around – add `CardID` field to both tables.
3. It is not clear for me the intention of joining `Customer` with `ORDER TYPE`. Consider changing names.

Also, even writing this small response it was so difficult to follow your table/column names, that contain spaces, underscores, mixed-case-names, singular/plural variants.

Please, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099684/db-design-critic-suggestions/10100537#10100537) and consider using some generic approach in naming your relations, columns and constraints.

Comment: In reply to point 2 of your post, that is why i asked this question -- i was wondering if i could connect the Payment table with the Order (renamed from ORDER TYPE)